# passport-facebook not doing a redirect

Tags: node.js, passport-facebook

Here's my silly nodejs module. When `passport.authenticate('facebook')` is called it just freezes.

I'm using Express 4.2.0. Any ideas?

The authenticate call doesn't block. How am I suppose to return from the function?

All the examples I've seen call `authenticate` in app.js. I don't want to configure authentication strategies in app.js.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var passport = require('passport')
var facebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new facebookStrategy({
        clientID: "xxx",
        clientSecret: "xxx",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    }
));

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook');
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **must** call `done()` in your `facebookStrategy` callback function. Without that, things hang because the calling of `done()` is how the system knows to proceed. Even if you just have stub code in there for now, you need at least `done()` to keep the control flow proceeding properly.

Secondly, `passport.authenticate` **returns** a middleware function, so you don't directly call it, you pass it on to express:

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('facebook')); //don't wrap here
```

The second part incorrect about your above `router.get` callback is it never responds, which is also a way to make express hang.

Once those are fixed, you'll need one more route to handle the facebook callback:

```
var options = {
  successRedirect: '/home',
  failureRedirect: '/bummer-dude'
};
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', options));
```